# A noncomplete graph $H$ of order $5$ or more with the property that $deg (u) ≠ deg (v)$ for every pair $u, v$ of nonadjacent vertices of $H$.

Tags: graph-theory

I'm working in the following graph theory excercise:

> Give an example or explain why no such example exists of a noncomplete graph $H$ of order $5$ or more with the property that $deg (u) ≠ deg (v)$ for every
>   pair $u, v$ of nonadjacent vertices of $H$.

I've reached the conclusion that is impossible that this graph exists because it can not be generated edges infinitely, is there a formalization that could help me to show it? Thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Comment: You might find it easier to think about things in terms of the contrapositive of the given statement: Every pair of vertices of the same degree must be adjacent.

Comment: I don't understand why you think the graph is impossible. What does "they can not be generated edges infinitely" mean? Is that a Google translation? Try wording it differently. By the way, what happens if your graph $H$ is the union of two complete graphs of different sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does
$$
H = ([5], \{(1,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4),(3,5),(4,5)\}).
$$
satisfy your requirements?

I found it by considering the complement, which has the property that every pair of *adjacent* vertices has distinct degrees.